# Propvariant to variant C#

Tags: c#, variant

I am a newbie in this. I am trying to convert propvariant to variant in C#

I have a code like this.

```
      public static object PropValueToVariant(PROPVARIANT Value)
    {
        object result;
        DateTime stTime;
        DateTime ftTime;
        object __Null;
        // Convert the prop variant to variant data type

        switch(Value.vt)
        {
            //@ Undeclared identifier(3): 'VT_I1'
            case VT_I1:
                //@ Unsupported property or method(C): 'bVal'
                result = Value.bVal;
                break;
            //@ Undeclared identifier(3): 'VT_UI1'
            case VT_UI1:
                //@ Unsupported property or method(C): 'bVal'
                result = Value.bVal;
                break;
            //@ Undeclared identifier(3): 'VT_I2'
            case VT_I2:
                //@ Unsupported property or method(C): 'iVal'
                result = Value.iVal;
                break;
            //@ Undeclared identifier(3): 'VT_UI2'
            case VT_UI2:
                //@ Unsupported property or method(C): 'uiVal'
                result = Value.uiVal;
                break;
            //@ Undeclared identifier(3): 'VT_I4'
            case VT_I4:
                //@ Unsupported property or method(C): 'lVal'
                result = Value.lVal;
                break;
            //@ Undeclared identifier(3): 'VT_UI4'
            case VT_UI4:
                //@ Unsupported property or method(C): 'ulVal'
                result = ((int)Value.ulVal);
                break;
            //@ Undeclared identifier(3): 'VT_I8'
            case VT_I8:
                //@ Unsupported property or method(C): 'hVal'
                //@ Unsupported property or method(D): 'LowPart'
                result = ((int)Value.hVal.LowPart);
                break;
            //@ Undeclared identifier(3): 'VT_UI8'
            case VT_UI8:
                //@ Unsupported property or method(C): 'uhVal'
                //@ Unsupported property or method(D): 'LowPart'
                result = ((int)Value.uhVal.LowPart);
                break;
            //@ Undeclared identifier(3): 'VT_BOOL'
            case VT_BOOL:
                //@ Unsupported property or method(C): 'boolVal'
                result = Value.boolVal;
                break;
            //@ Undeclared identifier(3): 'VT_R4'
            case VT_R4:
                //@ Unsupported property or method(C): 'fltVal'
                result = Value.fltVal;
                break;
            //@ Undeclared identifier(3): 'VT_R8'
            case VT_R8:
                //@ Unsupported property or method(C): 'dblVal'
                result = Value.dblVal;
                break;
            //@ Undeclared identifier(3): 'VT_CY'
            case VT_CY:
                //@ Unsupported property or method(C): 'cyVal'
                result = Value.cyVal;
                break;
            //@ Undeclared identifier(3): 'VT_ERROR'
            case VT_ERROR:
                //@ Unsupported property or method(C): 'scode'
                result = Value.scode;
                break;
            //@ Undeclared identifier(3): 'VT_DATE'
            case VT_DATE:
                //@ Unsupported property or method(C): 'date'
                result = Value.date;
                break;
            //@ Undeclared identifier(3): 'VT_FILETIME'
            case VT_FILETIME:
                //@ Unsupported property or method(C): 'filetime'
                //@ Unsupported function or procedure: 'FileTimeToLocalFileTime'
                FileTimeToLocalFileTime(Value.filetime, ftTime);
                //@ Undeclared identifier(3): 'FileTimeToSystemTime'
                FileTimeToSystemTime(ftTime, stTime);
                result = stTime;
                break;
            //@ Undeclared identifier(3): 'VT_CLSID'
            case VT_CLSID:
                //@ Unsupported property or method(C): 'puuid'
                result = Value.puuid.ToString();
                break;
            //@ Undeclared identifier(3): 'VT_BSTR'
            case VT_BSTR:
                //@ Unsupported property or method(C): 'bstrVal'
                result = Value.bstrVal;
                break;
            //@ Undeclared identifier(3): 'VT_LPSTR'
            case VT_LPSTR:
                //@ Unsupported property or method(C): 'pszVal'
                result = (Value.pszVal as string);
                break;
            //@ Undeclared identifier(3): 'VT_LPWSTR'
            case VT_LPWSTR:

                result = WideCharToString(Value.pwszVal);
                break;
            default:
                result = __Null;
                break;
        }
        return result;
    }
```

Why am I getting the Error for case names? also it doesnt understand ulval, lval, etc....

Thank you so much for help

Comment: This is sounding like "What does this do?". Go look up how to use the target language before asking here.

Comment: I am working on Converting delphi code to C# and the tool automatically converted in this. I have never worked on C# before

Comment: "Error for case names" what do you mean exactly?

Comment: "I have never worked on C# before" = "I don't know what the **** I'm doing, can you do my work for me?". research it before you ask on SO please.

Comment: azulflame. I figured out.
it should have been like this

{ case (ushort)VarEnum.VT_I1:
result = Convert.ToSByte(Value); break;
 case (ushort)VarEnum.VT_UI1:
 result = Convert.ToByte(Value);
 break;
}

so, because vt is ushort type , I have written (ushort) and VT_I1,VT_UI1,.... are part of System.Runtime.InteropServices.VarEnum.

SO I also added using System.Runtime.InteropServices.

Thank you all for the help. I was not here for getting my work done by someone else. All I wanted is the direction. :)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

you dont neet this function, here is the function already implemented in the .net framework:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices.marshal.getobjectfornativevariant.aspx

Comment: This method doesn't take PROPVARIANTs.

Answer (score 0):

You should use the `Marshal` class and a couple of P/Invoke calls:

- Allocate a 16-byte array (via, say, `AllocCoTaskMem`) (**Edit:** Make that 24 bytes for 64-bit processes)
- Zero it out with a P/Invoke call to `VariantInit`
- Then do the actual conversion, with a P/Invoke call to [PropVariantToVariant](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb776577(v=vs.85).aspx) to fill this buffer with variant data
- You can now get your object via `Marshal.GetObjectForNativeVariant`
- And don't forget to clean up:

  - A P/Invoke call to `PropVariantClear`
  - Another to `VariantClear`
  - And then give the unmanaged memory back with `Marshal.FreeCoTaskMem`.